# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

[image]I am trying to automate my web application using the python and selenium, I am facing the below issue.

Environment - Mac/Python/Selenium 
IDE - PyCharm

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver'
>   executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. because you haven't pass the Chrome binary which required by Selenium to drive your Chrome browser.

You need to download binary as per your OS from below URL :-

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/

Use below code :-

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "/Users/adam/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Change the path of chromedriver in above code

OR

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
cap = {'binary_location': /Users/adam/Downloads/chromedriver"}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=cap, executable_path="/Users/adam/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

OR

Alternatively you can use a direct path to the chromedriver like this:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Source:

[Running Selenium WebDriver python bindings in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-selenium-webdriver-python-bindings-in-chrome)

Comment: Shubham , I am using the MAC environment.

Comment: If you bothered to scroll down in the provided link, you would have noticed this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8946843/8085234

Comment: Download this :- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.32/chromedriver_mac64.zip

Comment: Add another code in answer .. refer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500606/set-chrome-browser-binary-to-chrome-webdriver-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the `chromedriver` binary from [**`ChromeDriver Download`**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) page and place it anywhere within your system. While you initiate the **`WebDriver`** instance you need to mention the absolute path of the **`ChromeDriver`** binary.

On my `Windows 8` system the following code block works perfect:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
```

Comment: @ShubhamJain It's clearly mentioned that the code block is based on `Windows 8` system.

Comment: Can any one help me regarding the mac environment.

Comment: @HillHacker Did you download the Mac platform dependent chromedriver binary version 2.32? Can you let me know the location where you have stored it?

Answer (score 0):

At firsts you need to download chrome driver from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads then unarchive it. then add this file to params of enviroments. And then write 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\YourPathofChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')