# Can I use Selenium and Brave together?

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu-18.04, brave-browser

Rencently I changed my web-browser to Brave, but I was working with chromedriver to automating some tasks

I've read some and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158434/how-to-run-selenium-tests-on-the-brave-web-browser) says that the version of ChromeDriver and Brave have to match, but I don't find driver to my current version only for **ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106**.

This is my Brave info: Versión 1.4.96 Chromium: **80.0.3987.132** (Official Build) (64-bits).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.binary_location = '/usr/bin/brave-browser '
driver_path = '/home/usr_1/Downloads/ML/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = option, executable_path = driver_path)
driver.get('https://pypi.org/')
```

Answer (score 1):

To open a [brave](/questions/tagged/brave) *Browsing Context* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  option.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe'
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=option)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com")
  ```