# Launch the Brave web browser on Linux using selenium & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, brave

I am trying to setup a hello world app to learn Selenium. I want to write a script that opens the Brave web browser.

I tried a few code scripts online and at Stack overflow and nothing seems to work.

```
const { Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver")

async function example() {

    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("brave").build();
    console.log(driver)
    await driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");



}


example();
```

The above script does not recognize brave so I changed forBrowser("brave) to "chrome". It still doesn't work.

I found the following code online that allows me to get the exact directory of the browser I want to launch, but I do not know how to combine it with what I already have.

```
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');


chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder('/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop').build());
```

I read the code below at another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158434/how-to-run-selenium-tests-on-the-brave-web-browser) but I am not sure how to launch a browser instance using it.

```
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options()

chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/bin/brave-browser')
```

**EDIT**

The code below is my latest attempt at cobbling together methods from around the web to make this work.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options()
chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath('/home/wktdev/Desktop/selenium/drivers/chrome/chromedriver')


let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    .build();


driver.get('http://example.com');
```

I get an error saying "Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. "

I am unsure how to proceed

**EDIT**
I have Chrome launching. Here is what I did:

I updated to the latest Chrome Browser.
I downloaded the newest chrome driver that mirrors my version of Chrome here:

```
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/
```

I created a random directory on the desktop such as blah/code and I put the downloaded files there.

I then opened a terminal window and added that directory to my computers path variable like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/some/new/path
```

I kept the current terminal window open and rand the node.js script and chrome opened.

I now need to know how to change this so that it opens Brave instead

Comment: Did you follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158434/how-to-run-selenium-tests-on-the-brave-web-browser ?

Comment: I read it and updated my post. The following code does not throw an error but I have no idea how to use it to launch a browser instance:  const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options()

chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/bin/brave-browser')

Comment: I don't know much about the JS syntax, so I won't answer. But I do know that, you would need chrome driver exe and brave file location to set the browser instance.

Comment: I have both, I just don't know how to incorporate them into the code properly

Answer (score 1):

As Brave went full-Chromium (starting from version 0.57), to open [brave](/questions/tagged/brave) browser you need to set *`setChromeBinaryPath`* towards the **brave** executable as follows:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options()
chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/bin/brave-browser')

let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('brave')
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    .build();

driver.get('http://example.com');
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to use Brave web browser with python, selenium and chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver/65030379#65030379)
- [Use Selenium with Brave Browser pass service object written in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69970256/use-selenium-with-brave-browser-pass-service-object-written-in-python/69981271#69981271)
- [How to initiate Brave browser using Selenium and Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626853/how-to-initiate-brave-browser-using-selenium-and-python-on-windows/62627392#62627392)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path to the brave executable with `setChromeBinaryPath`.
For example (on Windows):

```
chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath('C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe')
```

For me, I copied the `chromedriver.exe` file to my project folder. But you should also be able to place it anywhere in your `PATH` environment variable.