# Chrome canary headless mode does not work on windows10

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Google Chrome Canary does not work with headless on Windows.

Chrome headless does not work on windows. 
The Error happens like following when I tried to execute below code. 
But it works on non-headless mode.

I know Canary is unstable but I want to using it to learning about web advanced spec.

This error caused by bug in canary?
Or caused by my code?

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

op = Options()
op.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe"
op.add_argument("--headless")
op.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=op)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Error:

```
[1205/232511.644:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1017)] Lost UI shared context.
[1205/232511.644:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[1205/232511.644:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12022/devtools/browser/3d7c8ff8-625a-4326-b968-bbff
[1205/232511.714:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[1205/232511.714:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics
[1205/232511.714:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[1205/232511.714:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics
[1205/232513.037:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[1205/232513.037:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics
```

OS: windows 10 Home 1709
Chrome: 65.0.3285.0 (Official Build) canary 64bit
ChromeDriver: 2.33.506120

Comment: *"I know Canary is unstable"* - then what's the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set chrome browser binary to chrome webdriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500606/set-chrome-browser-binary-to-chrome-webdriver-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

As your error logs reports as follows :

```
[1205/232511.644:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1017)] Lost UI shared context.
[1205/232511.644:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[1205/232511.644:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics
```

I will suggest the following steps :

- Uninstall **`Google Chrome Canary`** from your system through `Revo Uninstaller`
- Use `CCleaner` tool to wipe off all the OS chores.
- Install fresh **`Google Chrome Canary`**
- Use the following code block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  op = Options()
  op.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe"
  op.add_argument("--headless")
  op.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=op, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  ```

> You can find about multiple ways to work with multiple **`Chrome Browser Binaries`** in [**`Set chrome browser binary to chrome webdriver in Python`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500606/set-chrome-browser-binary-to-chrome-webdriver-in-python/45503916#45503916) discussion.