# Which versions of Chromium, Selenium and Chromedriver are required to run Selenium on a Chromebook?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, chromebook

I'm want to run Selenium tests using Chromedriver on a Chromebook and I'm not able to get it to work.

**Setup**
I have [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) and [chromebrew](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew) installed. chromebrew has packages for  virtualenv and Python3.6, plus with `pip install Selenium` I got Selenium. From the [ChromeDriver ChromeOS documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/chromeos) I know the chromedriver is in `/usr/local/chromedriver`. Calling it:

```
chronos@localhost /usr/local/chromedriver $ chromedriver 
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24 on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

gives me the version and I only want to test `localhost` so I'm fine and have:

```
Versions:  
ChromiumOS 55.0.2883.100 (64-bit)  
Python 3.6  
Selenium bindings for Python 3.13.0  
Chromedriver 2.24
```

I (think I) understand that the Chromedriver behaves like a server on port 9515 waiting for calls from `test.py`. I fiddled around until I got no more errors for missing chromedriver/permissions/etc.

**Test File**
My test file only contains:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.binary_location = '/etc/chromium.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/chromedriver/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://localhost:8000")
```

If I call `python3 test.py` or `get("http://localhost:8000")` nothing happens and on my python3 call, I eventually end up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/chromedriver/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/demo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/demo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/demo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/demo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/demo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24,platform=Linux 3.14.0 x86_64)
```

I also found this test script on the [chromedriver documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) to run the chromedriver as a service with the same result as above:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service

service = service.Service('/usr/local/chromedriver/chromedriver')
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': '/etc/chromium.exe'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
driver.get('http://localhost:8000');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

You'll see I swapped Chrome with custom Chromium in the capabilities. From [chromedriver documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45503916/) this is the way to replace the default Chrome binary with a custom one.

I understand from this [github issue](https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/issues/133) that the problem could be that versions of components don't play nice with each other, but the [Chromedriver documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start) it points to doesn't really tell me where to start looking for which versions to try.

I think I have covered all cases except for incompatible versions, so question is, who can tell me which version of what can get this to run?

Comment: here we go: [compat matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133391/which-chromedriver-chrome-browser-version-compatible-in-selenium-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

There are numerous possibilities beyond this error as follows:

- As you are on *Linux OS* while you mention the absolute path of the *chromium* binary you need to strip the extension i.e. `.exe` as follows:

  ```
  chrome_options.binary_location = '/etc/chromium'
  ```
- While you initialize the *Chrome* browsing session you need to pass both the arguments **chrome_options** and **executable_path** as follows:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/chromedriver/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
  ```
- Just like regular *Chrome Browser* GA releases, *Chrome Team* does releases the *ChromeDriver* binaries with added/modified functionalities along with corrosponding supported *Chrome Browser* versions. You need to ensure that the `chrome` and `chromedriver` binaries which you are using are in sync following the [**Release Notes**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt).

> You can find a related discussion on versioning in [**`Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser/48551748#48551748)

However, your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.24*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.24*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.24/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v52-54**

- You are using *chrome=55.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.27*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v54-56**

So there is a clear mismatch between **ChromeDriver v2.24** and **Chrome Browser v55.0**

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.40**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v66-68*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.40 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: ah, wow, thanks, I'll go through the list and report back if I can solve it

Comment: I'm not there yet - see my [follow-up question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050259/why-does-dpkg-l-show-my-library-is-in-folder-usr-share-doc-when-it-doesnt-exi) but upgrading Chrome (v62 is [best I can do currently](https://nayuos.nexedi.com/)) and chromedriver to compatible version brought me on track with missing libraries. Let's see if I can get it to work. I'll mark this one as correct, Thanks for helping