# python selenium is there a way to manually set a path for chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I got this message:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of 
 ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91
 Current browser version is 90.0.4430.85 with binary path C:\ProgramFiles\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I am currently using the stable chrome version 90.0 as my daily driver. I also have a version 90.0 webdriver for it.

I want to test out something with 91.0 which is the beta version. I had it installed and also its version 91.0 webdriver.

Is there a way to keep both of them and launch the 91.0 webdriver with 91.0 chrome?

thank you, greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set chrome browser binary through chromedriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500606/set-chrome-browser-binary-through-chromedriver-in-python)

Comment: Certainly it does !