# Problem in Python with Chrome binary/chromedriver: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am aware that there are more threads to this case but I am new here and cannot comment. I am using Python Cumminity Edition 3.11

I have installed Google Chrome
Checked that I have the right path for the chromedriver
I could somehow not install chrome binary because my python version is to high but read here that this is not needed anymore with the new selenium version

```
import calendar
from datetime import date
from selenium import webdriver
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

date_today = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-6)
day = calendar.monthrange(date_today.year, date_today.month)[1]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
site = "https://www.ariva.de/allianz-aktie/kurse/historische-kurse?go=1&boerse_id=6&month=" + str(date_today.year) +"-" + str(date_today.month) + "-" + str(day) + "&currency=&clean_split=1&clean_bezug=1"
wd = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\haemm\\Videos\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
wd.get(site)
html_sel = wd.page_source
df = pd.read_html(html_sel)
```

And the error message is:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

I would really appreciate the help! Thanks!

I would hope for all tables are displayed and data can be used.

Comment: Solved with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500606/set-chrome-browser-binary-through-chromedriver-in-python